# LINQ .Where .Max and Writing to File

Tags: c#, linq

I have a program which writes its output to log files to folders in the following format:

```
Car7 Lap1 00-00-21-5290000
```

Everything is working fine, but I want to append a # to the filename of the fastest lap time for each car. In order to do so, I placed the following LINQ query inside my car object to act on the List property of Car:

```
public List<Lap> Laps { get; set; } = new List<Lap>();
public TimeSpan FastestLap => Laps.Where(lap => lap.Number is not null and not 0).Min(lap => lap.LapTime);
```

I'm using the .Where clause as laps can sometimes be null or 0, and when I write to disk things initially appear to be working:

```
Car8 Lap39 00-01-07-8900000#
```

However, only 8 cars get written to disk as opposed to the full field of 20 cars. If I remove only the .Where part of my property above, all the cars and car folders write properly, except the Lap 0 files are typically marked as the fastest lap (which makes sense since they contain incomplete times).

My writing to disk method looks like this:

```
foreach (var car in carList)

{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(@$"{outputPath}\{logFileName}\Car{car.Number}");

     foreach (var lap in car.Laps)
     {
          using TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@$"{outputPath}\{logFileName}\Car{car.Number}\Car{car.Number} Lap{lap.Number} {lap.LapTime.ToString().Replace(":", "-").Replace(".", "-")}{(lap.LapTime == car.FastestLap ? "#" : "")}.csv");

          WriteCsvHeader(tw);

          foreach (var telemetryRecord in lap.UniqueTelemetryRecords)
          {
              WriteCsvLine(tw, lap, telemetryRecord);
          }
     }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening so that all cars and car folders get written to disk?

Comment: If `LapTime` is a `TimeSpan`, are you sure it compiles `Min(lap => lap.LapTime)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, use a getter to perform a bit more advanced logic when retrieving the value.

Replace this line:

```
public TimeSpan FastestLap => Laps.Where(lap => lap.Number is not null and not 0).Min(lap => lap.LapTime);
```

With this:

```
public TimeSpan FastestLap
{
     get
     {
          if(Laps.Where(lap => lap.Number is not null and not 0).Count() > 0)
               return Laps.Where(lap => lap.Number is not null and not 0).Min(lap => lap.LapTime);
          else
               return Laps.Min(lap => lap.LapTime);
     }
}
```

This is essentially saying that if any non zero laps exist, get the lowest value. Otherwise, it'll just return the zero value.

Comment: @JMR Sure thing. Remember, the property is read only in this instance. So there's no way to update it's value manually. You can learn more here: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_properties.asp

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to implement `IComparable<T>` on your class:

```
public class Lap : IComparable<Lap>
{
    public int CompareTo(Lap other)
    {
         //if both have nulls or zero they are equal
        if((this.Number == null || this.Number == 0) && (other == null || other.Number == null || other.Number == 0) return 0;

        // If other is null or the other.Number is null or zero this instance is first in sort order
        if (other == null || other.Number == null || other.Number == 0) return -1;

        //if this instance has null or zero for the number and other doesn't this instance comes after other
        if((this.Number == null || this.Number == 0) && other != null && other.Number != null && other.Number != 0) return 1;

        //Comparison depends on this.LapTime to other.LapTime
        return LapTime.CompareTo(other.LapTime);
    }

    ......
}
```

Then you could just call `.Sort()` on the `List<Lap>` and your first item in the List will be your fastest lap that is not null or zero. Append the # to the first item in the list and you don't need an extra method in your class.